# SQL View - exclude record before a date range

Tags: sql-server

I got a complicated query where I need to exclude a list of products from this query result if there date range is before a certain date but include if after the date. Each record got its own date but the date for exclusion/include is fixed.

I get the list of products from another view.

My SQL is rusty (I normally code a lot of Objective C), please can somebody help me with an idea on how to write this query?

Sample query:

select AuthDate, ProductId, *
from ProductOrders

The ProductOrders table contain a bunch of orders for all kind of products, here I want to exclude a list of products that come from another view (vwExcludeProducts) ONLY if the AuthDate is before a certain date like 1 Sep 2011 but include if after 1 Sep 2011.

vwExcludeProducts return only a ProductId of the list of products to b excluded, so I think I need to join this view with the ProductOrders table and only look at it if AuthDate is < 1 Sep 2011.

ProductOrders sample data:

Product Id | Description | AuthDate
1            Desc 1        2011-08-30
2            Desc 2        2011-08-30
3            Desc 3        2011-08-30
4            Desc 4        2011-08-30 
5            Desc 5        2011-09-01

In this case the vwExcludeProducts view return that I want to hide ProductId 4 so it should hide that but show the others... If vwExcludeProducts also contain ProductId 5 then it will not hide since its after/include 1 Sep 2011.

Thanks

Comment: If you make more effort with your question, for example tell us the names of your tables and columns or show us the dataset you are working with and what you want to achieve, I'm sure someone will post the SQL to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
SELECT AuthDate, ProductId, * 
FROM ProductOrders 
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vwExcludeProductOrders WHERE ProductId = ProductOrders.ProductId) AND AuthDate < '2011-09-01')
OR AuthDate >= '2011-09-01'
```

Obviously using * to select all columns isn't best practice, you should specify just the columns you need to retrieve, but with no information about requirements it is difficult to know what to suggest.

Comment: correct yes, but only for a given set of products... This ProductOrders table contain a all bunch of products that always must b included but for a certain set of products it must exclude before 1 Sep 2011 and include after this date.

Comment: I really think you need to edit your original post with more detail about the table structures and what you are trying to achieve because I am failing to understand what you need

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I think is correct based on my understanding of the requirements

Comment: This even exclude products from the table that isn't part of vwExcludeProductOrders

Comment: Maybe posting some sample data might help my understanding